# Prevent onChangeListener from firing when form is prepouplated

Tags: java, android

I have a text field called VIN Number that when the user types in, if they reach 17 characters, I want to fire off a `LookUpVin()` method.

The problem is, when the user navigates to the screen, if the VIN is pre-poplated the it calls `LookUpVin()`, erasing anything the user may have typed in other fields (Make, Model, Year, etc..).

***How do I only fire the change listener when the user is typing, not if the form is being populated via a data source?***

```
 editVIN = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editVIN);
    editVIN.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);

    editVIN.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
editVIN.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    Utilities.hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
                    if (editVIN.getText().length() == 17) {
                        doVINLookup();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        editVIN.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
        editVIN.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (editVIN.getText().length() == 17) {
                    doVINLookup();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: have you tried adding the listener after the field is prepoluated? or check to see if s.toString() equals the prepopulated text and if so, return before executing your code in afterTextChanged(Editable s)

Comment: Exactly what callback is being called, that bothers you?